# Java Reflection: how can you get constructor of a class you don't know?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say you're making a general reflection class. You're given the name of the class in string format:
So you do Class.forName(class_name) to get the class name.

Next step would be to get the constructor and you can do Class.forName(class_name).getConstructor(null) assuming that there isn't any args.

How do you now get an instance of this? You would have to downcast but what do you downcast to?
class_name name = (*what goes here*) Class.forName(class_name).getConstructor(null).newInstance(null)

I tried to put in the class_name in the parenthesis class_name name = (class_name) Class.forName(class_name).getConstructor(null).newInstance(null) but getting an error. Well not compiling.

Update:
Only thing known is that the constructor doesn't have any args, and instance doesn't have parameters. So you can pass null to both.

Comment: Do you know *nothing* about the class whose name you're given? If you can guarantee that it implements a particular interface, you can cast to that interface.

Comment: How would you go about casting it to that interface? Only thing known is that the constructor doesn't have any args, and instance doesn't have parameters. So you can pass null to both. So let's say someone is using my reflection code to test their class. I don't know the name of their class, so I'll pass it as a String classname arg. But it also means that the class exists I just don't know the name of it. But I also know that the constructor and new instance doesn't require anything

Comment: Don’t pass null.  Just leave the arguments empty.  Everywhere you’re writing “(null)”, you should be writing “()”.  For example: `Class.forName(class_name).getConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do with the instance after its created. If you have no guarantees about the class, you can only assign instances to variables of type `Object`.

Comment: Why do you think you have to cast it to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible.

If you load the class using `Class.forName(someClassName)`, it means you do not know *at compile time* what the class will be, you will only know it at runtime (when the value of `someClassName` will be defined).

That means, you can't code based on that specific type (because if you want to have typed code at compile time, then you should know the exact type at compile time and that's not your case).

However, even though you can only declare your instance as `Object obj = ...` instead of `SomeClassName obj = ...` (which I understand is what you wanted to do), be reassured that your `obj` will actually be an instance of `SomeClassName` at runtime, even if the compiler doesn't know it yet.

If you add more details about what you're trying to do (I mean why do you need to cast the reflected instance to the specific type), then I can complete my answer to address your exact concern.

**EDIT**
To answer to the questions in the comments:

> so inherently Java knows that it's a Foo class but it'll just return a
> generic Object because it wants to be sure that it's correct?

No.
When coding there are two phases: compile-time and run-time.
The compile-time is the moment when the code is compiled into an executable.
The run-time is the moment when the code is executed.

Take the initial expression of your question:

```
Object obj = Class.forName(class_name).getConstructor().newInstance();
```

When does the variable `class_name` take a concrete value? Well, that's at runtime (when the code runs).

That means, there is simply *no way* that the compiler can ever know what the return of this instruction will be, not until the time the code is executing, before it can only say that it will be an `Object` (because in Java, everything is an `Object`).

But again, *at runtime*, if you're passing the name of the class `Foo`, the the instance will be a `Foo` (assuming of course that the reflective operation works correctly).

> the only time you cast is when you know what class your dealing with. But then what is the point of ever casting it?

That's correct, you can only cast when you know what to cast into.
And there is a sure point about casting.

Let's take a very simple example.
Imagine that you have a `String` object, like `String str = "something that is a string";`.
Knowing that `str` is a `String`, you can call methods that belong to the class `String`, for example:

```
str.split(" "); //<-- valid because str is a String
str.replace("o", "c"); //<-- valid because str is a String
```

Now, imagine that `str` is a `String`, but it's declared as `Object`:

```
Object str = "something that is a string";
```

Even though `str` is concretely a `String`, you won't be able to use that code anymore:

```
str.split(" "); //<-- INVALID: the class Object doesn't have a method .split()
str.replace("o", "c"); //<-- INVALID: the class Object doesn't have a method .replace()
```

So if that was the case, you would cast `str` into a `String` and you would be able to do what you were doing:

```
Object str = "something that is a string";
String str2 = (String) str;
str2.split(...);
str2.replace(...);
etc.
```

And of course, the cast is only possible when `Object str` is actually a `String`, if it was (for example) an `Integer`, that would have raised a `ClassCastException`.

So why do you need to cast? Because *at compile time*, you need to write code against a specific object, and for that you need to cast to access the methods and properties correctly.

Comment: So let's say someone is using my reflection code to test their class. I don't know the name of their class, so I'll pass it as a String classname arg. But it also means that the class exists I just don't know the name of it. When I get the newInstance i'll be getting back a Java.Lang.Object but i wanted it to be more specific to the class that is being worked on, that's why the downcast.

Comment: @rd1346 yes, but that's not my question. Imagine that you're asked to load a class `Foo`. The statement `Class.forName("Foo").getConstructor().newInstance()` will return you an `Object` which concretely is a `Foo`. Why do you need to cast it into `Foo`? What do you need that for? As I stated above, it's impossible to do it. But if you explain _why_ you want to cast it, I may think of another solution.

Comment: Oh I think I get your point, so inherently Java knows that it's a Foo class but it'll just return a generic Object because it wants to be sure that it's correct? If I'm understanding it correct, the only time you cast is when you know what class your dealing with. But then what is the point of ever casting it?

Comment: @rd1346 I've made an edit to my answer in order to answer your last questions.

Answer (score 0):

The classes `Class` and `Constructor` provide everything
you need to accomplish your goal.

1. From `Class.forName(String)` you get the `Class` object.
2. By calling its `getConstructors()` method you get an array of
   `Constructor` objects (representing the declarations of the
   constructors).
   See the [javadoc of `Class.getConstructors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors--).
3. Then by calling the `getParameterTypes()` method of any of these
   `Constructor`s you get an array of `Class` objects
   (the types of the formal parameters of a constructor).
   See the [javadoc of `Constructor.getParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getParameterTypes--).
4. Now you know what types of parameters any constructor needs.
   Then you can actually invoke the constructor with such parameters
   by calling `constructor.newInstance(param1, param2, ...)`.

Example: with this code

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.util.HashMap");
System.out.println(clazz);
Constructor<?>[] constructors = clazz.getConstructors();
for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors) {
    System.out.println("  constructor: " + constructor);
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
    for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes) {
        System.out.println("    parameterType: " + parameterType);
    }
}
```

you get all constructors of `java.util.HashMap` and their parameter types:

```
class java.util.HashMap
  constructor: public java.util.HashMap(int)
    parameterType: int
  constructor: public java.util.HashMap(int,float)
    parameterType: int
    parameterType: float
  constructor: public java.util.HashMap(java.util.Map)
    parameterType: interface java.util.Map
  constructor: public java.util.HashMap()
```

Comment: This explains some basics about reflection, but doesn't address the point of OP which is very clear: he wants to cast the instance to the concrete class, which is impossible at compile time.